# DocumentFile.length() is extremely slow, want direct access to sd card

Tags: android, documentfile

I want to give the user the option to save images on their sd card and I want to be able to calculate the sizes of folders of such images. I find that `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` returns internal storage. The only way I can find the sd card is by using an `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` request. But this means I have to use DocumentFiles rather than regular Files. I can only get a content uri, not a direct path to the sd card itself.

So, `File.length()` works well with internal storage but `DocumentFile.length()` is extremely slow with external storage. Is there any way to get the size of a folder based on its content uri without it taking forever? Or can I somehow find an actual path to the sd card and use Files instead? I found a folder like `/storage/3857-3732` but I don't seem to have permission to write to it (yes I have `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission).

Comment: `isFile()` and `isDirectory()` work fine (true when appropriate). I got `android.support.v4.provider.TreeDocumentFile` for both files and folders.

Comment: What does "extremely slow" mean? Compared to what? Does it take 200ms per call to `length()`? 2 seconds per call? Did you observe, that calculating total size takes N seconds for directory with N nested items, but K<N seconds when using a `File` API? If so, please add those numbers to the question.

Comment: In case someone comes up here still looking for a solution,
I built a wrapper over this with some pretty good performance.

You can check the wrapper & performance info. here:
https://github.com/ItzNotABug/DocumentFileCompat